# What is the output of the below code python code

Tags: python

[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS6Vg.png)

Can anybody explain the below code

```
x=0

while x<7:
    if x==5:
        continue
    print(f'value of x is:{x}')
    x+=1
```

the output of this code is:

```
value of x is:0
value of x is:1
value of x is:2
value of x is:3
value of x is:4
```

Comment: Please post the actual code here instead of using an external image.  It keeps everything in one place.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't *skipping* the value `5`; it's falling into an [*infinite loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) at value 5.

The `continue` statement restarts the loop, but because you never change the value of `x` before doing so, on subsequent passes through the loop the `x == 5` conditional continues to be satisfied, and the same behavior is repeated *ad infinitum*.

You don't see this because you are running in Jupyter where it is not obvious that the program has not returned. If running at a Python shell, or writing a script and executing it with the python interpreter, it spins forever, pegs the CPU at 100% and never returns to accept further input.

---

## Resolution

There are multiple ways to fix this.

### (Recommended) Use a `for` loop

A `for` loop iterates through a collection of values (perhaps an iterable or the values `yield`ed by a generator function) until there are no remaining values. By contrast, a `while` loop runs forever until its condition is false.

Where you have a known, limited number of items to iterate over, it is normally more idiomatic to use such a loop, as shown in the example. `range(x, y)` is a simple mechanism to obtain the integers in the interval `[x, y)`.

```py
for x in range(0, 7):
  if x == 5:
    continue
  print(f'value of {x}')
```

---

Alternative solutions using a `while` loop (included here for their instructive nature):

### Increment `x` on every loop pass

Increment the value of `x` on each pass through the loop

```py
x = -1
while x < 7:
  x += 1
  if x == 5:
    continue
  print(f'value of {x}')
```

### Refactor the logic to use a conditional around the `print` call

```py
x = 0
while x < 7:
  if x != 5:
    print(f'value of {x}')
  x += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because once you've reached `5` you `continue`, hence you start over the loop without incrementing the value of `x`.

Congrats, you wrote an infinite loop ;-)

In order to fix this, you should increment `x` anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Since the fifth iteration the loop becames infinitive loop. To prevent this behaviour you must move "x+=1" line to be the first operation in the iteration:

```
   x = 0
   while x <= 7:
       x += 1
       if x == 5:
          continue
       print(x)
```

But in general, if you want to iterate X times, you'd better use for loop

```
for x in range(8):
    if x == 5: continue
    print(x)
```